# Show that, for any infinite set X, there exists an injective but non-surjective map and a surjective but non-injective map

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that, FOR ANY infinite set X, there exists:
(i) an injective but non-surjective map h : X → X,
(ii) a surjective but non-injective map h : X → X.

really tripped up at this saying "for any". I feel like I cant just show one example. If there is something good I can read on this please link.

Comment: [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set)

Comment: You can now upvote also.

Answer (score 1):

It is known that every infinite set contains a countable subset (axiom of choice). So let $X$ contain the subset $A:=\{a_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$  with $a_n\not=a_m$ for $n\not=m$. Then $f:A\to A$ with $f(a_n):=a_{n+1}$ is injective and not surjective. Likewise $g:A\to A$, $g(a_1):=a_2$, $g(a_n):=a_n$ for $n\geq 2$ is surjective but not injective. Let $X:=A\cup Y$ with $A\cap Y=\emptyset$. Then $F,G:X\to X$ defined by $F(y):=G(y):=y$ for $y\in Y$ and by $F(a):=f(a), G(a):=g(a)$ for $a\in A$ are as desired.

*Edit:* $g$ should be defined differently. $g(a_1):=a_1$, $g(a_{n}):=a_{n-1}$ for $n\geq 2$.

Comment: $G$ isn't surjective.

Comment: It is since $g$ is.

Comment: Isn't $a_1$ missed?

Comment: Yes, I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is infinite, then there is an infinite subset $Y=\{y_1, y_2, \ldots\}\subset X$.

1. Define $g:X\to X$ so that $g(x)=x$ if $x\in X\backslash Y$ and set $g(y_i)=y_{i+1}$. Then $g$ is injective, but $y_1\notin g(X)$.
2. Define $h:X\to X$ so that $h(x)=x$ for $x\in X\backslash Y$, $h(y_{2n})=y_n$ and $h(y_{2n+1})=y_n$. Then $h$ is surjective, but $h(y_2)=h(y_3)= y_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $X$ is infinite.   Let $C=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots\}$ be a countably infinite subset.

Define $h:X\to X$ by $h(x)=x, x\in X\setminus C$ and $h(x_i)=x_{i+1},x_i\in C$.

h is injective but not surjective.

I'll leave the second to you.